# WSO2 API Manager Federated IDP Access Token

Tags: wso2-api-manager, openid-connect, federation, wso2-identity-server

How can I pass the access token created on an OpenIdConnect Federated IDP to the developer application?

Currently, the federated access token doesn't get passed through the API Manager and the API Manager generates a new access token for the application.

Comment: Seems, you haven't configure the federated IDP in correct way. Please refer this blog,http://nuwanzone.blogspot.com/2015/10/getting-access-tokens-for-wso2-api.html. you can get some idea.

Comment: What are the WSO2 products are you using in your environment and versions ?

Comment: We are using version 1.9.1. I have also tested it in version 1.10.0. Looking at the code it doesn't seem like this feature has been added yet. Check out line 364 in https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/c28325310b6e700b8bbec2edd3c3a6ad012d3d64/components/application-authenticators/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.oidc/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/oidc/OpenIDConnectAuthenticator.java

Comment: To be clear, the application receives an access token but the access token is one that is generated by the wso2 product and not the federated IDP. Does it still sound like we have our environment setup incorrectly?? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to plug in an external IDP and generate access tokens using an out-of-the-box API Manager. But you can implement a custom keymanager implementation and plug external third party keymanager to API manager and then use that tokens. See [Configuring a Third-Party Key Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager) in the product documentation regarding this. It has a sample where "Surf OAuth Authorization Server" is use as the key manager. You will be able to implement similar thing for your scenario.

following are some good posts related to this feature.

https://amilasnotes.wordpress.com/2015/06/20/customizing-key-validation-flow/
https://amilasnotes.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/integrating-with-a-third-party-oauth-provider-overview/
https://amilasnotes.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/provisioning-oauth-clients-created-out-of-band/